# How to send Hubspot Double opt-in emails using REST API?

Tags: node.js, hubspot

We are creating contacts on Hubspot using its REST APIs.
The form we are using is not a Hubspot form, it is our custom form built in React.js.

We need to send double opt-in emails to users after users subscribe through our form.

Currently, it is creating only contacts using that form.

We set up everything to use double opt-in feature.

But it is not sending opt-in emails to users. 
Is there any way to send emails to users after create contacts?

Answer (score 1):

[According to HubSpot](https://integrate.hubspot.com/t/how-to-send-double-opt-in-email-using-rest-apis/12255), it is not currently possible to send double opt-in emails from HubSpot using the API.